# In regard to "belong"

Tags: word-usage

*I note that this item does not belong on the long side in the drawing.*

I want to know if the usage of "belong" is correct in the above sentence.

Comment: There’s nothing grammatically wrong with it.  What do you intend the sentence to mean?

Comment: I want to mean according to the drawing for assembly, the item should not be put on the long side, instead, it should be on the lid or other sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you explained in comment, the original sentence seems to concern the location of the item *on the drawing*, not on the article being constructed. So I suggest:

> I note from the drawing that this item does not belong on the long
>   side.

The usage of "belong" is fine.